# When are unexpected alerts checked?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, alert

I am writing an automation using Chromedriver and Selenium and Java.  One step calls a method which does something like

```
 save.click()
```

which clicks a save button.  Sometimes this just does a save, and other times it causes an alert (like please fill out the date field or what have you).

so I have code like

```
 page.save(); // which calls the above method
 String alertMsg = waitForAlertTextAndClose(30);
```

(waitForAlertMessageAndClose() basically does a wait for the alert and close, as it says.  I will post the code farther below if you want to see it.

Sometimes after clicking save, moving onto the next step would cause a StaleElementReferenceException, because the page had not finished loading from the save.

So I added this (waitForStaleElement() just waits for a stale element and sets an AssertionError if the element does not go stale and waitForXPathVisibility() waits for the xpath or throws an assertion.  In this case I don't care if it doesn't go stale because sometimes it won't.

I modified the save:

```
 try {
    save.click();
    waitForStaleElement("Save to go stale", save);
    waitForXpathVisibility("SAVE button", saveXPath);
 } catch (AssertionError ex) {
   ; // this is OK because sometimes it won't go stale
 }
```

trouble is, now when there is an alert it throws an UnexpectedAlertOpenError in the method and never gets propagated back to the caller.

So I was just curious.  At which points (or executions) will Chromedriver throw the UnexpectedAlertOpenError?  It was not doing it before I added the wait.

--- waitForAlertTextAndClose:

```
public String waitForAlertTextAndClose(int timeOutInSeconds) {
    String alertMessage = null;
    Alert element = null;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
    try {
        element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        alertMessage = element.getText();
        element.accept();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        throw new AssertionError("Alert not present after " + timeOutInSeconds + " seconds.");
    }
    return alertMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void AcceptAlert(IWebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait)
{
  IAlert alert = wait.Until<IAlert>(alrt => WaitForAlert(driver));
  driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();

}

public static IAlert WaitForAlert(IWebDriver driver)
{
  try
  {
    return driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
  }
  catch (NoAlertPresentException)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

As above you can simply try for alert separately and get the text of alert in AcceptAlert() function.
Hopefully this works for you!!

Comment: Works in general, but if the alert happens in the method prior to calling the above, the above won't work because it will give the error before getting there.